# Katana+OWIN Context Get HTTP Referrer?

Tags: owin, katana

IOwinContext does not appear to have the HTTP Referrer in it, and I need to grab it. What is the right way to get that particular variable? IOwinContext has several Typed PEMs but I don't see referer in particular.

The system I am working is self-hosted.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what host you are using System.web or SelfOwinHost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OwinContext doesn't have 'HTTP Referer' as item in Request header. This has been renamed in Owin self host context. It's now known as 'Referer'. So once you have object of owin context you can get the information by using:

```
context.Request.Headers["Referer"]
```

Comment: As silly as it may sound you save me days of struggling.